# Replacement plug on MagSafe adapter?

Tags: power, magsafe

The plug portion of my power adapter broke off. Fortunately, this piece of the adapter seems to just slide off of the main adapter body, attaching via a round metal piece. So basically I would just need to find a new plug assembly and slide it on.

Has anyone ever done this, or know where I could find such a replacement part? Can't find anything on Apple.com.

Here's an example of what my adapter looks like now:

[image]

It looks like this is intentionally replaceable for the purpose of international electrical socket compatibility, so you'd think it'd be easy to find a new plug piece... ?

Comment: Also - look in your original mac box - there should be a long three prong cord that will fit the same place as the broken two-prong plastic "duck-head" that is missing in the picture above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the "broken" piece in to the store (or call in to AppleCare) they can sell you a "replacement" piece as a "repair" part. Don't worry - it is a brand new piece, not something that is repaired. I think they cost around $10.

I don't think you can order just that piece - but it is included in the updated [Apple World Travel Adapter Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB974ZM/B) along with an iPad charger, USB cord and the worldwide plugs. This kit is $39 in the US.

Comment: Thanks @bmike! Would you happen to know if this would be covered under an active AppleCare?

Comment: The warranty (and therefore AppleCare) specifically excludes external damage - so it's really up to AppleCare. I've never seen one break other than due to physical forces, but I would say take it in (or call) and ask. My personal experience is AppleCare looks for any reason to cover things (i.e. consumer friendly)- so even though it's probably not covered, you might ask anyhow. I've only broken these by the adapter shearing them - when a pet (or me being careless) side swipes it while it's in the wall. I've been able to see the plastic welds were there and it simply broke.

Comment: yep, thats exactly what happened to it. i did remember about the three prong cord after posting this. originally, i wasn't sure what it was for. then i put 2 and 2 together... ;)